# How can I deal with `No enum constant` error in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am creating a JOB in `AWS Glue` but it shows below error in the last step.

```
{"service":"AWSGlue","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"InvalidInputException","requestId":"ad9ee511-adb8-11e9-9bbf-9d08424a9846","errorMessage":"No enum constant com.amazonaws.services.glue.FileFormat.UNKNOWN","type":"AwsServiceError"}
```

The column mapping is shown correctly as below screenshot.

[image]

what I don't understand is which input field has an invalid data? Glue doesn't give me more detailed information about this error. How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Can you check and confirm what is the classification in your Glue data catalog for this table?

Comment: I didn't set any classification in my Glue.

Comment: Hey @ZhaoYi, Did you ever figure out the solution? I am running into the same problem and it will be really useful if you can please tell. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, because accidentally I tried to **write the data to my DynamoDB table** (as my **Target**). When I changed to S3. It worked.
You can learn more about it on [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html)
[Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=306406) is the issue raised in amazon related to this.

Comment: I can confirm that the error string "No enum constant" in the 400 InvalidInputException appeared for me as well when my Glue job was mistakenly writing back to my DynamoDB table. When I fixed that to write to S3, as I had intended, the job worked.